# Call razor method from onclick in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to find a way to execute a method in my layout view only when a link is clicked. Here's my code so far:

The method I want to call (also in the view):

```
@functions{
    public void Logout()
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
    }
}
```

The link that'll be clicked to call that method:

```
<a onclick="// Call the method from here" href="#">Log Out</a>
```

The question is, how do I go about this?

Comment: If you want to use onclick as you have written in your post, you have to use Javascript. There is no way to do an onlick in C#

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403758/call-razor-function-from-javascript, it stated you need to use AJAX callback to access server-side methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a controller action in your account controller and then invoke it.

For example, one quick way is to add action method:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
}
```

and in view you can do it via js:

```
<a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Logout","Account")'" href="#">Log Out</a>
```

A better way is to create action as `HttpPost` and do it via a form post. but the above example gives an idea how you can do that on the link click on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by href

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")">Log Out</a>
```